# Passing a token in the header of a ListAPIView endpoint from one api to another Django REST

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 APIs in Django REST.

One API generates a JWT token.

I want to send that token to another API.

In the first API (API 1), I am posting the token to the ListItems class (/someendpoint/) in the header of the POST request.

```
import requests

token = "someToken"
requests.post("/posting/token", {token})
```

In another API (API 2), I want to receive that JWT token in the request header :

in views.py:

```
class ListItems(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [ItemsPermissions]
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
```

in urls.py:

```
url_patterns = [
    path("/someendpoint/list/", ListItems.as_view(),
]
```

What is the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: Let me clarify. First we send a request to API-1 which would return a JWT token. Then all you need is to just pass that returned token to API-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication):

> For clients to authenticate, the token key should be included in the Authorization HTTP header. The key should be prefixed by the string literal `"Token"`, with whitespace separating the two strings.

But it isn't limited to the prefix `"Token"` as noted:

> Note: If you want to use a different keyword in the header, such as `Bearer`, simply subclass TokenAuthentication and set the keyword class variable.

Since you are using [JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=authorization#auth-header-types) token:

> views requiring authentication would look for a header with the following format: `Authorization: Bearer <token>`. This setting may also contain a list or tuple of possible header types (e.g. ('**Bearer**', '**JWT**')

So you could either try:

```
response = requests.get("/someendpoint/list/", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer eyJxxxxxx"})
```

Or:

```
response = requests.get("/someendpoint/list/", headers={"Authorization": "JWT eyJxxxxxx"})
```

Make sure that you have properly setup the authentication classes as documented [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) either via:

1. views.py

```
class ListItems(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [
        # Only list here what you needed
        rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication,
        rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication,
    ]
    ...
```

2. or settings.py

```
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        # Only list here what you needed
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ],
    ...
}
...
```